# Prime decomposition

Tags: prime-factoring

I'm trying to take a user-entered number and determine if it's a prime number or not. If it is not prime, I want to display the prime factors for that number. I need to use only JOptionPane. No matter what I try my code doesn't read any odd numbers (21, 25, 105 etc) as primes even though they are. What am I doing wrong?

```
    do
    {   
        enteredNum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a positive"
                + " integer","enter number",1);
        int number = Integer.parseInt(enteredNum); //Enter number and convert to integer
        if (number < 0){
            break;
        }

        counter = 2;
        isPrime = true;

        while(isPrime && (counter < number)){
            if((number%counter)== 0){
                isPrime = false;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your entered number, "+number+" is not prime."
                        + "\nIts prime decomposition is "+counter+" X "+(number/counter)+".",
                        "Prime number", 1);
                break;
            }
            else {
                counter = counter + 1;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, number+"is a prime number", "Prime number", 1);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your definition of prime is incorrect: 21 = 3 * 7, 25 = 5 * 5, and 105 = 3 * 5 * 7 are not prime.